# Combining select statements with dates

Tags: php, sql, database

Please help me, I want my SQL Select statement combined in one query

```
<?php

Total Assigned = SELECT date(DATE_DISTRIBUTE)
     , COUNT(DATE_DISTRIBUTE) AS TotalAssigned
  FROM ata_report_extracted WHERE STATUS ='DISTRIBUTED'
 GROUP BY date(DATE_DISTRIBUTE) ";


Total Handled = "SELECT date(DATE_HANDLED)
     , COUNT(DATE_HANDLED) AS TotalHandled
  FROM ata_report_extracted WHERE PROS_DESCRIPTION NOT IN ('Open', 'Acknowledged', 'Fallout', 'Cleared') AND STATUS ='DISTRIBUTED'
 GROUP BY date(DATE_HANDLED) ";

Total Resolved ="SELECT date(DATE_HANDLED)
     , COUNT(DATE_HANDLED) AS TotalResolved
  FROM ata_report_extracted WHERE PROS_DESCRIPTION = 'Closed' AND STATUS ='DISTRIBUTED'
 GROUP BY date(DATE_HANDLED) ";

TotalDispatch ="SELECT date(DATE_HANDLED)
     , COUNT(DATE_HANDLED) AS TotalDispatch
  FROM ata_report_extracted WHERE PROS_DESCRIPTION ='Dispatch' AND STATUS ='DISTRIBUTED'
 GROUP BY date(DATE_HANDLED) ";


TotalPending ="SELECT date(DATE_HANDLED)
     , COUNT(DATE_HANDLED) AS TotalPending
  FROM ata_report_extracted WHERE PROS_DESCRIPTION IN ('TOKUNDEROB', 'CALLNOANSWER') AND STATUS ='DISTRIBUTED'
 GROUP BY date(DATE_HANDLED) ";

 ?>


<?php

Total Assigned = SELECT date(DATE_DISTRIBUTE)
     , COUNT(DATE_DISTRIBUTE) AS TotalAssigned
  FROM ata_report_extracted WHERE STATUS ='DISTRIBUTED'
 GROUP BY date(DATE_DISTRIBUTE) ";


Total Handled = "SELECT date(DATE_HANDLED)
     , COUNT(DATE_HANDLED) AS TotalHandled
  FROM ata_report_extracted WHERE PROS_DESCRIPTION NOT IN ('Open', 'Acknowledged', 'Fallout', 'Cleared') AND STATUS ='DISTRIBUTED'
 GROUP BY date(DATE_HANDLED) ";

Total Resolved ="SELECT date(DATE_HANDLED)
     , COUNT(DATE_HANDLED) AS TotalResolved
  FROM ata_report_extracted WHERE PROS_DESCRIPTION = 'Closed' AND STATUS ='DISTRIBUTED'
 GROUP BY date(DATE_HANDLED) ";

TotalDispatch ="SELECT date(DATE_HANDLED)
     , COUNT(DATE_HANDLED) AS TotalDispatch
  FROM ata_report_extracted WHERE PROS_DESCRIPTION ='Dispatch' AND STATUS ='DISTRIBUTED'
 GROUP BY date(DATE_HANDLED) ";


TotalPending ="SELECT date(DATE_HANDLED)
     , COUNT(DATE_HANDLED) AS TotalPending
  FROM ata_report_extracted WHERE PROS_DESCRIPTION IN ('TOKUNDEROB', 'CALLNOANSWER') AND STATUS ='DISTRIBUTED'
 GROUP BY date(DATE_HANDLED) ";

 ?>
```

Display total reports daily in one query

Comment: And what is it you want, what is the definition of "total reports daily"?

Comment: Date Total Assigned Total Handled Total Resolved Total Dispatch 
16/05/2019 1              0                      0                           0                   
17/05/2019 5              2                  1                                 0                    Iwant result like this :)

Comment: Edit your question with that information instead of posting it as a comment and make sure it is easy to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All requirements explained in comments are incorporated in the following query. I used FULL JOIN so that if a date available in one query and not in other one that also comes in the output.

```
SELECT 
CASE
    WHEN A.Date_Han_Dst IS NULL THEN B.Date_Han_Dst 
    ELSE A.Date_Han_Dst
END AS [Date_Han_Dst],
A.TotalHandled,
A.TotalResolved,
A.TotalDispatch,
A.TotalPending,
B.TotalAssigned
FROM 
(
    SELECT date(DATE_HANDLED)  AS [Date_Han_Dst],
    SUM(CASE WHEN PROS_DESCRIPTION NOT IN ('Open', 'Acknowledged', 'Fallout', 'Cleared') AND STATUS ='DISTRIBUTED' THEN 1 ELSE 0  END) AS TotalHandled,
    SUM(CASE WHEN PROS_DESCRIPTION = 'Closed' AND STATUS ='DISTRIBUTED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalResolved,
    SUM(CASE WHEN PROS_DESCRIPTION ='Dispatch' AND STATUS ='DISTRIBUTED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalDispatch,
    SUM(CASE WHEN PROS_DESCRIPTION IN ('TOKUNDEROB', 'CALLNOANSWER') AND STATUS ='DISTRIBUTED' THEN 1 ELSE 0  END) AS TotalPending
    FROM ata_report_extracted GROUP BY date(DATE_HANDLED)
)A
FULL JOIN
(
    SELECT date(DATE_DISTRIBUTE)  AS [Date_Han_Dst],
    SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS ='DISTRIBUTED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) TotalAssigned
    FROM ata_report_extracted GROUP BY date(DATE_DISTRIBUTE) 
)B
ON A.Date_Han_Dst = B.Date_Han_Dst
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193581/discussion-on-answer-by-mkrabbani-combining-select-statements-with-dates).